# AttributeError: 'Field parent_id not found in browse_record(hr.employee, 6)

Tags: openerp-7

I cant access employee table ie `hr_employee` table fields from my new module.

It shows error as

`AttributeError: 'Field parent_id not found in browse_record(hr.employee, 6)`

Any one please help!!!

Anu

Comment: Please provide your code. Without that we can't help you.

Comment: if i login as admin i can access the table, but not for other users. Do you have any idea , what the issue is?my code is given below ids = args['creditnote_no']
    values = {'status':'approved'}
    employee = self.pool.get('hr.employee').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
    args['manager_id'] = employee.parent_id.user_id.id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

changing code to:

`resource_id = self.pool.get('resource.resource').search(cr, uid, [('user_id','=', uid)][0]
Emp_id = self.pool.get('hr.employee').search(cr, uid, [('resource_id','=', resource_id)][0]`

corrected my issue.